# JVM remote connection refused

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, jvm, podman

I have complated kubernetes setup however when I connect to kubernetes service with Remote JVM debug, I am getting error "Unable to open debugger port (localhost:30081): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect""

Could you help me ?

Thanks

I wait to connect with remote kubernetes services